# Python, using Selenium how to clean page_source from char like /a0:

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver to get page source. But I get back a source filled with the /a0:, which I have read ment non-breaking space. So I was wondering:

A. How to get read of it, should I clean the source once I got it, or can I do anything in advance?

B. What reason is there to place it on the HTML in the first place, first time I encountered such a thing.

Example for code:

```
......<a0:div style="position: absolute; top: -1000px; height: 1px; width: 1px;">
<a0:object data="https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/js/element/hrs.swf" height="500"
id="fI0hpn482ja" name="fI0hpn482ja" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400">
<a0:param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></a0:param></a0:object></a0:div>
<a0:iframe class="goog-te-menu-frame skiptranslate" frameborder="0" style="visibility:
visible; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; width: 731px; height: 274px; display: none;">
</a0:iframe></a0:body></a0:html></body></html>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can repalce them with an empty string. Common usage could be like this:

```
def get_clean_string(string, substring):
    while substring in string:
        string = string.replace(substring, '')
    return string
```

and the result:

```
In [24]: get_clean_string('replacemeHeresWhatINeed', 'replaceme')
Out[24]: 'HeresWhatINeed'
```

2.Maybe you should specify encoding in your source. Python uses ASCII by default ([here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)). In my project I encounter russian chars all the time, so all my files are encoded to utf-8 in the first line

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```